# Is null when new ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I had a error when watching online product, code is like this, but an `NullPointedException` bother me, this error only appear once, and I can not  reappear it. I can not understand why `ArrayList` is `[null, 1]`:

```
public void test4() {
    class PlayerTask {
        List<Integer> targetValueList;

        List<Integer> getTargetValueList() {
            if (null == targetValueList) {
                init();
            }
            return targetValueList;
        }

        private void init() {
            targetValueList = new ArrayList<>();
            targetValueList.add(Integer.parseInt("1"));
        }
    }
    PlayerTask task = new PlayerTask();

    //some code1
    new Thread(() -> {
        task.getTargetValueList().get(0); // NullPointException ,real array is [null, 1]
    }).start();

    //some code2
    new Thread(() -> {
        task.getTargetValueList().size();
    }).start();

    // some code ...
    new Thread(() -> {
        task.getTargetValueList().get(0);
    }).start();

    // ....
    ///task.getTargetValueList().get(..)...
}
```

Comment: `PlayerTask` is not thread safe, and you're accessing it with multiple threads at once, that's why. You'd have to at least make your initialization of the `targetValueList` synchronized

Answer (score 4):

Your code is multi-threaded yet you are not guarding against possible [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) when creating and accessing `new ArrayList<>()`. The quickest way to solve this problem would be to `synchronize` `getTargetValueList()` method:

```
synchronized List<Integer> getTargetValueList() {
    if (null == targetValueList) {
        init();
    }
    return targetValueList;
}
```

Take a moment to read [Safe Publication and Safe Initialization in Java](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/safe-public-construction/). It gives great insight how this approach can be improved and why certain patterns like Double-Checked Locking are a bad idea.

If you want to learn more about concurrency the book [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Brian-Goetz/dp/0321349601) is a good starting point.

Comment: Thx . but i have d question, in multi-thread environment， new ArrayList<>() and add(1), maybe task.getTargetValueList()  result is null, but why the real result is [null,1]? how null value added to this list?

Comment: @doubleevil reasoning about incorrect concurrent code is hard. Perhaps the `Integer` object created in thread 1 is not visible to thread 2 because there was no memory barrier to ensure it's publication? See [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).